# Reading Multiple lines until EOF

Tags: c, malloc, stdout, stdin

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

//the function
char* scan(char *string)
{
  int c; //as getchar() returns `int`
  string = malloc(sizeof(char)); //allocating memory

  string[0]='\0';

  for(int i=0; i<100 && (c=getchar())!='\n' && c != EOF ; i++)
  {
    string = realloc(string, (i+2)*sizeof(char)); //reallocating memory
    string[i] = (char) c; //type casting `int` to `char`
    string[i+1] = '\0'; //inserting null character at the end
  }

  return string;
}
char** bigScan(char **string)
{

  int c;
  string=malloc(sizeof(char *));
  string[0]='\0';
  for(int i=0;(c=getchar()!=EOF);i++)
  {
    *string = realloc(string, (i+2)*sizeof(char *)); //reallocating memory
    string[i] = scan(string[i]); //type casting `int` to `char`
    string[i+1] = '\0'; //inserting null character at the end

  }
  return string;

}
int main(void)
{
  char **buf; //pointer to hold base address of string
  buf=bigScan(buf);
  printf("%s\n",buf[0] );


}
```

So basically the scan function reads each line until either EOF or new line.The job of bigScan is to read multiple lines (pointer to strings) by invoking the scan function until we hit EOF. So essentially the big scan returns pointer to pointers and we can read the entire text using this.
What am I doing wrong in my approach ?
Basically invoking the scan function in my bigScan until I Hit EOF.

```
  Ideal Input:
  "Hi guys and girls
  This is a message in multiple lines."
  Ideal Output:
  "Hi guys and girls
  This is a message in multiple lines."
```

Comment: If you have a maximum of 100 `char`s, you might as well statically allocate. I would think all those `realloc`s are going to be slow.

Answer (score 2):

1. The `(c=getchar()!=EOF)` inside `bigScan` is invalid. It assigns the value of `1` or `0` to c, as the `bool` value is the result of `!=` comparison.
2. The `getchar()` inside `bigScan` will make you loose one character per line, as that character is nowhere saved.
3. The allocation in `bigScan` is invalid. You shouldn't allocate the memory for string `*string = realloc(string`, but you should allocate the memory for pointers themselves, ie. `string = realloc(string, ... sizeof(char*))`.
4. `NULL` is the terminating value used for pointers. Don't use `'\0'` for pointers.
5. Use `size_t` to store sizes.
6. There is little point in passing parameters value if you are overwriting them. In this function the variable `a` is unused `void f(int a) { a = 1; }` as the variable `string` in your both functions are assigned immediately after entering the function.
7. The function `scan` has a hard limit of `i<100` characters.

Below is somewhat fixed version of your functions. With also renamed variables. And removed parameters. And different indentation. And with `assert`ions from the standard `#include <assert.h>` to use as a primitive error checking. And with `ungetc` so the character read in `bigScan` doesn't disappear. And I haven't run this code, so it has ton of errors.

```
char* scan(void)
{
  char *string = malloc(sizeof(*string));
  assert(string != NULL);
  string[0] = '\0';
  size_t stringlen = 1;

  for(int c; (c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF;) {
    void * const ptr = realloc(string, (stringlen + 1) * sizeof(*string));
    assert(ptr != NULL);
    stringlen++;
    string[stringlen - 2] = c;
    string[stringlen - 1] = '\0'; //inserting null character at the end
  }

  return string;
}


char** bigScan(void)
{
  char **strings = malloc(sizeof(*strings));
  assert(strings != NULL);
  strings[0] = NULL;
  size_t stringslen = 1;

  for(int c; (c = getchar()) != EOF;) {
    ungetc(c);

    void * const ptr = realloc(strings, (stringslen + 1) * sizeof(*strings)); 
    assert(ptr != NULL);
    strings = ptr;
    stringslen++;
    strings[stringslen - 2] = scan();
    strings[stringslen - 1] = NULL;

  }

  return strings;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.But the unget(c) call seems to complain when I try to compile the program.

Comment: Och it's [ungetc(int, FILE*)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ungetc) so ut should be `ungetc(c, stdin)`